# UINavigation bar reload/refresh button code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I know that at the end my question me sound silly and easy to solve but I have been trying for hours to make it work but it does not work at all.

I have a UINavigation bar with a "back" and a "refresh" button. The back button works perfectly but I haven't found any way to make the refresh button to work.

[image: UINavigation bar with button]

What I want from the refresh button is to load the whole view again. Like refreshing the whole "viewWillAppear" section.
I have tried view reload and setNeedsDisplay but none of the work.
Is there any way that I can do this?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you just trying to get the code in viewWillAppear to execute again?

Comment: I want the whole view to reload.  It is a view that takes your GPS coordinates and redirect you to a website.  Therefore I want the whole procedure to take place again because you may change position.  This can be done by pressing back and then reload the view because I have my code in viewWillAppear but I want to make it work through the "refresh" button as well

Comment: Without actually seeing your code, I would recommend moving whatever logic you're doing in your viewWillAppear to its own method, so you can call that method when the refresh button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all functions called in viewWillAppear: into a seperate function with appropriate name and call them when someone clicks the refresh button and in the viewWillAppear:. Example

```
-(void) gpsRedirect{
     //Do stuff that you did in viewWillAppear:
}
```

And use this code for creating a selector that's activated for touch up inside event upon a button. This will trigger the method gpsRedirect which contains what you previously did in viewWillAppear:

```
[barButtonItemName addTarget:self
action:@selector(gpsRedirect)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```